# Getting different behavior between useState() and useRef() + useState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-state

I am getting different behavior between the two code blocks when I believe they should be the same. My goal is to update compass heading using `watchHeadingAsync` and perform and animation from the previous heading to the new heading.

The first code block results in `heading[0]` always being `0` and `heading[1]` being the current heading. The second block performs as expected. Is there some race condition I am unaware of that is causing this? Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```js
const [heading, setHeading] = useState([0,0]);

useEffect(() => {
    Location.watchHeadingAsync((headObj) => {
        let h = Math.round(headObj.magHeading) * -1;
        setHeading([heading[1], h]);
    });
}, []);

console.log(heading[0], '->', heading[1]);
```

```js
const [heading, setHeading] = useState([0,0]);
const oldHeading = useRef(0);
const newHeading = useRef(0);

useEffect(() => {
    Location.watchHeadingAsync((headObj) => {
        let h = Math.round(headObj.magHeading) * -1;
        oldHeading.current = newHeading.current;
        newHeading.current = h;
        setHeading([oldHeading.current, newHeading.current]);
    });
}, []);

console.log(heading[0], '->', heading[1]);
```

Comment: Note that if you had a linter set up, with React rules installed, it would have detected this issue. (Specifically, it would have warned you that the effect depends on `heading` but its list of dependencies doesn't include `heading`: https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#specifying-reactive-dependencies .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `heading` variable inside the `useEffect` callback is the constant value from when the effect ran. Indeed, it's always `[0, 0]` and never changes. To fix this [stale closure](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function) problem, you want to use the [updater callback variant](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) of the state setter:

```
useEffect(() => {
    Location.watchHeadingAsync((headObj) => {
        let h = Math.round(headObj.magHeading) * -1;
        setHeading(prevHeading => [prevHeading[1], h]);
    });
}, []);
```

Do not use refs as a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're observing different behavior between the two code blocks is indeed related to a race condition.
In this block,

```
const [heading, setHeading] = useState([0,0]);

useEffect(() => {
    Location.watchHeadingAsync((headObj) => {
        let h = Math.round(headObj.magHeading) * -1;
        setHeading([heading[1], h]);
    });
}, []);
```

you're setting the heading state based on the current value of heading, but since setHeading is asynchronous, it won't immediately update the state.
in the second block, using useRef ensures that you capture the correct previous heading value before updating the state, thus producing the expected behavior.

Answer (score -1):

The difference in behavior between the two code blocks stems from how you're managing state updates in the `useEffect` hook. Let's break down the issue:

Code Block 1:

- You're using a single state variable `heading` as an array to store both the old and new headings.
- Inside `useEffect`, you update the state using `setHeading([heading[1], h])`. This creates a new array with the previous heading at index 1 and the new heading at index 0.
- However, React performs state updates asynchronously. So, when you call `setHeading`, the state might not be updated immediately.

Code Block 2:

- You're using two separate state variables: `oldHeading` and `newHeading`.
- Inside `useEffect`, you update `oldHeading.current` and `newHeading.current` directly. These are ref values, which hold a mutable reference to a value. So, the changes are reflected immediately.
- Then, you update the `heading` state using `setHeading([oldHeading.current, newHeading.current])`. This ensures you're setting the state with the latest values from the refs.

I don't know whether the issue in the first block is technically a race condition or not, but it is an asynchronous update behavior of React's state management (useState()).

Comment: "*React performs state updates asynchronously. So, when you call `setHeading`, the state might not be updated immediately. In the next render, you log the `heading` state, which might still have the old values.*" - no.

Comment: Even if the state is updated later (asynchronously), React never renders with the outdated state. The re-rendering happens only after the updates are applied - asynchronously as well.

Comment: I still have a doubt sir. React doesn't provide the updated value in a case like useState hook until the re-render happens right and that is why we also use updater callbacks. Then which part of the statement is incorrect in my answer. I hope you explain this because I'm a learner still. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That the setter doesn't return the updated value, and that the `const` in the current render cycle cannot change, are separate issues. The statement which I quoted in my first comment is incorrect.